# how does tensorflow train RNNs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I just read through and ran the code here: https://tomaxent.com/2017/04/26/LSTM-by-Example-using-Tensorflow-Text-Generate/

(this guy rips off the following medium.com article, but I can't access medium.com from my work computer); https://medium.com/towards-data-science/lstm-by-example-using-tensorflow-feb0c1968537

From my previous reading, it is my understanding that to train RNNs, we have to 'unwrap' them into feed forward networks (FFN) for a certain number of steps (along with an extra input for the "x at time t"), and set it so that all the weights in the FFN that correspond to a single weight in the RNN are equal.

I'm looking at the code and I don't see any 'unwrapping' step, or even a variable indicating the number of steps for which we want to unwrap.

Is there another way to train an RNN? Am I just missing the line in the code where that variable is defined?

Comment: RNNs are trained using backprop through time. It is true that at each timestep the weights are the same (until they are update after a batch).

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken there is no such 'unwrapping step'.We generally "unroll" a RNN in-order to understand its working properly (through each time step).
Now,coming to Tensorflow Implementation I found this repo:[MuhammedBuyukkinaci/TensorFlow-Text-Generator](https://github.com/MuhammedBuyukkinaci/TensorFlow-Text-Generator/blob/master/tensorflow_text_generator.py) to be very useful and this might clear up your most of the doubts.

Other Useful Links:

[Tensorflow-RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent)

[Basic_Rnn_Cell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/BasicRNNCell)

[Static_RNN Cell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn)